# How to call a method multiple times at once for a file

Tags: c#

I have a Person model class as following;

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I get the FirstName and LastName from the user and validate them. Then I create a user name for each first and last name entered by the user with the following method;

```
public static string CreateUserName(Person person)
{
    return $"{person.LastName}{person.FirstName.Substring(0,2)}";
}
```

I'm able to do this one person at a time by running the program manually each time. What I want to know how to do is, suppose I have multiple lines of data stored in a CSV file which consists of FirstName and LastName and I read that file, then generate a user name for each row in that file at once with my CreateUserName method.

The output will be printed on the console and Person class will be used for other operations also.

Comment: `IEnumerable<string> CreateUserNames(IList<Person> people) { return people.Select(p => CreateUserName(p)); }`?

Comment: Use `foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(...))` to read the file, `line.Split(',')` as a simplistic way of splitting the CSV data, make a Person from your split bits, call your method

Comment: [Loops - The complete C# tutorial](https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/control-structures/loops/). Channel 9 video: [C#: What are Loops?](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/CSharp-101/CSharp-What-are-Loops).

Comment: Do you want to output a file, or the console? Please be specific on how you want the program to work. Also if `Person` going to be used for anything else, or is the program ends when the username is calculated? All of the above contribute to the design of programs.

Comment: The question is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Csv content:

```
FirstName;LastName
FirstName1;LastName1
FirstName2;LastName2
FirstName3;LastName3
```

Code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Logins
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static string CreateUserName(Person person) =>
            $"{person.LastName}{person.FirstName.Substring(0, 2)}";
            
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.csv");

            var result = lines.Skip(1)
                .Aggregate(new Dictionary<string, Person>(), (dict, x) =>
                {
                    var items = x.Split(';');

                    var person = new Person { FirstName = items[0], LastName = items[1] };

                    if (!dict.TryAdd(CreateUserName(person), person))
                        throw new Exception("User with such username already exists!");

                    return dict;
                });

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Username: '{item.Key}' for {item.Value.FirstName} {item.Value.LastName}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Username: 'LastName1Fi' for FirstName1 LastName1
Username: 'LastName2Fi' for FirstName2 LastName2
Username: 'LastName3Fi' for FirstName3 LastName3
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following demo code:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName 
        // Calculate UserName from first and last
        => $"{LastName}{FirstName.Substring(0, 2)}";

    public static Person Parse(string csvLine)
    // Transform a text line "First, Last" into
    // an object of Person
    {
        var parts = csvLine.Split(',');
        if (parts.Length>=2)
        {
            return new Person()
            {
                FirstName = parts[0].Trim(),
                LastName = parts[1].Trim()
            };
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(csvLine));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csv = @"First,Last
Jack, Mas
Jake, Moon
John, Mira
Jonas, Master
Jacob, Meek
Josselyn, Moore
Joanna, Milka";
        var fs = new System.IO.StringReader(csv);
        fs.ReadLine(); // eat up first line
        var list = new List<Person>();
        while (fs.Peek()!=-1)
        {
            var person = Person.Parse(fs.ReadLine());
            list.Add(person);
        }

        // create a list of usernames, each in a new line

        var unames = string.Join(
            Environment.NewLine, 
            list.Select((person) => person.UserName));

        Console.WriteLine(unames);
    }
}
```

That outputs

[image: scr]